# ï»¿ character encoding issue with .get response

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, character-encoding

I understand that the ï»¿ character string is generated when there's a BOM character mismatch. I'm getting them at the beginning of a response from a jQuery .get() call. For the time being, I'm hacking the response and stripping out the characters, but I'd like to understand why this is happening.

The existing site includes the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and I've tried adding the header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

before the title tag, both by itself and in conjunction with the meta tag. Regardless of whether either of these tags exists, Firefox reports that the page has UTF-8 encoding. I've tried replacing the .get() call with an .ajax() call that specifies the encoding, to no avail:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type:'GET',
            url: 'common/includes/FilterDataLog.cfm',
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            data: 'column='+selectedValue+'&filterValue='+filterValue+'&filterID='+filterID+'&configFile=log/log.xml',
            success: function(response){
                //response = response.replace('ï»¿', '');
                thisTextFilter.replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
```

The FilterDataLog.cfm page returns:

```
<div id="" class="fl txt_input_container">
<input type="text" class="txtvalueFilter" id="myFilterID" name="txtvalueFilter" value="#url.filterValue#"/>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $('#myFilterID').autocomplete({
            delay: 500,
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "cfc/autoSuggestLog.cfc?method=lookupSomething&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                      search: request.term,
                      maxRows: 30
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                      response(data);
                    }                   
                })
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {     
                if (!ui.item) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I've found no other places in the site where character encoding is being set, so am stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to check here.

1. First, make sure your IDE is saving your .cfm/.cfc files correctly. If you are using an Eclipse based editor such as CFBuilder, CFEclipse or some other plugin for Eclipse you can click **Window > Preferences** and then navigate to **General > Workspace**. Make sure your text **file encoding is 'UTF-8'**. I have a feeling this is your issue. If you are not using one of the more popular ColdFusion editors you'll need to consult with your own IDE help files. Once complete, re-save your file(s) and try again.
2. If step one did not fix the issue, try placing a  at the head of your CFC: `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8"/>`

Answer (score 1):

To determine if the issue is originating from the IDE I would copy and paste your code into a text editor such as NotePad++. There you can then select **Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 without BOM**, then save and re-run the file. If the error doesn't occur then you have a setting in your IDE to change.

You don't mention your servers, are you running a standalone copy of ColdFusion? Or is it running through IIS, Apache Tomcat, Apache HTTPD? Any one of those could be the source of the BOM insertion.